# Is there a way to return the search term with the Foursquare user search API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm doing bulk user lookups via email address (e.g. users/search? email=joe@foo.com, fred@bar.com, etc), but I noticed that it's not returning the email addresses with the search results.  Is there anyway to do this?

Alternatively, I could do a single email address search per request, or do a user lookup by id on all the results I get back, but these options seem wasteful and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User email is not one of the fields that the API returns for `/users`, see:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user.html

Usually API's don't return emails in the clear.